# mod_rewrite leads to 404

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, querystring

I'm trying to redirect (internally) `example.com/snippets/_filename_` to `example.com/snippets/?f=_filename_` using `mod_rewrite`... And it is not working.

The contents of my .htaccess file, which is placed inside of the `snippets` directory are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^snippets/([^/\.]+)$ /snippets/?f=$1 [L]
```

This solution, but it doesn't seem to work on my Apache 2.4 server, and instead causes a 404 Error.

Comment: did you check your apache error log to see what it's trying to get?  maybe that will be the clue to where it's gone wrong.

Comment: unfortunately not; still getting the same result.